# Why is "das Weib" grammatically neuter?

Tags: etymology, gender, history

The word *das Weib*, meaning *woman*, is grammatically neuter.  While the gender of nouns is generally unpredictable from their meaning, it is unusual that a word with such an explicitly feminine meaning (can't get more feminine in meaning than "woman"!) would be grammatically neuter.

Is there a simple explanation for this, based on the history / etymology of the word?

I am expecting something comparable to the explanation of why *Fräulein* is also neuter: because the (diminutive) suffix *-lein* always creates neuter words, regardless of the root's meaning.  I expect the explanation for *Weib* would need to go back much further in history though (the Old English cognate, [wif](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wif#Old_English), was also neuter).

Feel free to migrate to Linguistics.SE if it fits better there.

Comment: Note that independent of whatever etymological explanations there may be for the word originally being neuter, it has remained so throughout its history. Apparently a mismatch between grammatical gender and "extragrammatical" gender is easily tolerated.

Comment: Also in Dutch: *het wijf*.

Comment: @DavidVogt – Particularly if the real gender is feminine, apparently.

Comment: I guess, the root problem is your assumption, that substantives representing persons are a special case and handled separately. They are not. Not only are numerous counterexamples like *das Mädchen*, *das Kind*, and there are also colliding rules, that diminuitives become neuter as *das Männchen*.

Comment: @guidot, Mädchen, like Fräulein, is originally a diminutive, so this is not a very good example.

Comment: @EndreBoth What do you mean by "the _real gender_ is feminine"? The word _Weib_ has neuter gender, no matter if you qualify this as being _real_ or _unreal_ or whatever. Furthermore, it has _feminine sex_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich "real" in the sense of the gender of the person referred to, sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @EndreBoth You confuse _gender_ and _sex_!

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I would think [any](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gender) [dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gender) backs up my casual use of the term, but I appreciate your opinion. Maybe we should head over to [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I gave this question a -1 because although OP obviously knows the difference between gender and sex and also knows about the unrelatedness of the two (»While the gender of nouns is generally unpredictable from their meaning«), he goes on to ask (paraphrased) »why is *Weib* neuter although it denotes a female«.

Comment: @Philipp, the question is very reasonable, because in German words denoting male humans or animals are usually male and words denoting females are usually female. Exceptions exist and are interesting and worth investigating, which is what the question does.

Comment: @Philipp Especially when you try to correct others, it is important that you don't spread wildy incorrect misinformation like you do here. Grammatical gender and biological sex is strongly correlated in all Indo-European languages and the grammatical gender system probably originates from differences in biological sex.

Comment: Das Weib ist sächlich weil die Sache weiblich ist. :)

Comment: @userunknown Das führt zu der Frage, ob denn nicht eigentlich "sächlich" das wahre "weiblich" ist und umgkehrt. Und die Frage lauten müsste, warum sächlich und weiblich ihre Position getauscht haben? ;-)

Comment: @IQV: Ich hänge auch der Ansicht an, dass es kein wahres weiblich oder wahres männlich gibt. Der Hammer ist nicht männlicher als die Zange und der Löffel nicht als die Gabel. Und das Messer ist auch nicht das wahre weiblich. Die grammatischen Sachverhalte mit den Begriffen des Paarungsgeschehens zu besetzen war ein Unfall mit Spätfolgen - Geschlecht A, B, C hätte man wählen sollen oder Piff, Paff und Puff.

Comment: @Userunknown. Ja, aber so ganz ohne Zusammenhang ist es sprachgechichtlich sicherlich nicht. Die Spätaffen, die angefangen haben, ihre Grunz- und Quietschlaute so zu modifizieren, dass etwas herauskam, was wir heute Grammatik, Morphologie, etc. nennen, wären ja sicherlich nicht auf die Idee gekommen, erkennbar un-sexy Dingen wie Tischen und Löffeln ein grammatisches Geschlecht aufzudrängen, wenn nicht ihre Sprache eben diese grammatische Geschlecht schon gehabt hätte, und zwar vermutlich, weil die Teilung Männlein-Weiblein für ihre Lebenswelt und Weltauffassung elementar war.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Soweit ich weiß wurde der/die/das benutzt bevor es dafür den Begriff "sprachliches Geschlecht" gab und es kommt auch nicht daher, vom Menschen, und hat sich dann über unbelebte Dinge und Ideen ausgebreitet, sondern es kommt aus der gänzlich (sexuell) ungeschlechtlichen Sphäre und hat dann erst auch Menschen umfasst und dann erst den Namen "Geschlecht" bekommen. Dass aus der Wichtigkeit m/w eine Aufteilung von Messer/Gabel/Löffel in Geschlechter folgt sehe ich nicht - das wäre anders, wenn wirklich alle oder mindestens fast alle Sachen sächlich wären. Sind sie aber nicht.

Comment: Ich staunte etwas wegen *Wicht* ~ *Wucht* "Mädchen" unter [/wiki/Friesische Sprachen](de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friesische_Sprachen] in den Sprachbeispielen. Vgl etwa "Wuchtbrumme". Old-Frisian *wicht* indiziert [Kroonen p. 578] als "weight" unter PGem "**\*wehti 2** f. 'weight'", jedoch Dutch *wicht* "girl" unter gleichlautend "**\*wehti 1** f. 'thing'" neben "Go. *waihts* f. 'thing, entity, matter' […] Far[oese] *vaettur* f. 'spirit' […] OS[axon] *wiht* n. 'something' […] OHG *wiht* n. 'demon, being, thing', G *Wicht* m. 'midget'": ety unsicher. Dachte, das wäre wichtig. viz IE \*weH-? "winzig"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the etymology of *Weib* is unknown ([1](https://dwds.de/wb/Weib),[2](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GW12159#XGW12159)), there is also no way to explain its gender.

Comment: Grammatical gender is not necessarily related to etymology. It is not uncommon that cognates in different Germanic languages have different genders. In this case, the Norwegian cognate "viv" is e.g. masculine, the Danish cognate "viv" is common gender and the Swedish cognate "viv" is neuter.

Comment: @jarnbjo, still, when I read the entry in DWB (Grimm), it seems like the word has been neuter as far as it can be traced back, and they think that this should be taken into account when considering possible origins.

Comment: Your last comment makes sense, but I found your *answer* pretty vague. It is not necessarily required to know the etymology of a word to explain its gender.

Comment: You could say that "das Weib" is an abbreviation of "das Weibsbild".

Comment: @mic, just as one can always invent etymologies.

Comment: @mic: Nein, kann man nicht. Also sagen kann man es schon, nur glauben nicht.

Answer (score 5):

'Das Weib' and its cognates is or has been neuter in most Germanic languages. The word dates at least back to Proto-Germanic in the period before common era, and was already then neuter. There are conflicting information about the origin of the word. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wife) relates the word *possibly* to Proto-Indo-European *gʰwíh₂bʰ-, which had a different meaning.

One likely explanation, is actually that the word, be it *gʰwíh₂bʰ- or not, originally was of neuter gender, but had a different meaning and therefore did not deviate from the usual correlation. While the meaning changed to 'a female person', the neuter gender was kept.

Several comments and answers seem to implicate that grammatical gender and biological sex are two completely different things. This is simply wrong. There is a strong correlation between grammatical gender and biological sex in all Indo-European languages with a distinction between masculine and feminine genders. The split into masculine and feminine genders is also assumed to be rooted in the distinction between biological sexes and goes back to some time in the Proto-Indo-European period. It is assumed that the Proto-Indo-European language originally only had a distinction between animate and inanimate objects and that the animate 'gender' split into masculine and feminine, while the inanimate gender turned into neuter. In the North Germanic languages and some Slavic languages, there is still remains of a gender-like distinction between animate and inanimate things.

There are exeptions, e.g. the already mentioned German words 'Fräulein' and 'Mädchen', which are neuter because all diminutive forms are neuter, but *in general*, most words solely referring to male persons are of the masculine grammatical gender and most words solely referring to female persons are of the feminine grammatical gender. With a few more exceptions, but still *in general*, this also applies to words referring to animals. It is a very legit question to ask why 'das Weib' does not follow the general rule.

**Edit:** Based on user unknown's comment, it seems that I have to clarfiy, as he didn't understand what I wrote. I do not claim, that all words of masculine gender refer to objects of male biological sex, that all words of feminine gender refer to objects of female biological sex and that all words of neuter gender refer to things. I am saying that *if* a word refers solely to a male living object, the word has most likely masculine grammatical gender: der Mann, der Ochse, der Hengst. *If* a word refers solely to a female living object, the word has most likely feminine gender: die Frau, die Kuh, die Stute.

To quote from Wikipedia on the topic [Grammatical vs. natural gender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender#Grammatical_vs._natural_gender):

> The natural gender of a noun, pronoun or noun phrase is a gender to
>   which it would be expected to belong based on relevant attributes of
>   its referent. This usually means masculine or feminine, depending on
>   the referent's sex (or gender in the sociological sense). For example,
>   in Spanish, mujer ("woman") is feminine whereas hombre ("man") is
>   masculine; these attributions occur solely due to the semantically
>   inherent gender character of each noun.
>
> The grammatical gender of a noun does not always coincide with its
>   natural gender. An example of this is the German word Mädchen
>   ("girl"); this is derived from Maid "maiden", umlauted to "Mäd-" with
>   the diminutive suffix -chen, and this suffix always makes the noun
>   grammatically neuter. Hence the grammatical gender of Mädchen is
>   neuter, although its natural gender is feminine (because it refers to
>   a female person).
>
> **Normally, such exceptions are a small minority.**

Comment: Das Reh ist also die Frau vom Hirsch? Katzenfutter ist für weibliche Katzen? Das Schwein ist geschlechtslos, die Maus weiblich, der Habicht männlich, die Taube weiblich usw.? M.W. ist der Ursprung des grammatikalischen Geschlechts keine Unterscheidung weiblich/männlich und auch nicht belebt/unbelebt (die Sache, der Hammer, die Zange, ...). Historisch trat erst das Femininum als Endung auf, dann kam das sächliche, und das unspezifische wurde dann aus einer Art Symmetriedenken männlich genannt. Hence generisches Maskulinum.

Comment: @userunknown also bei den Rehen paaren sich der Bock mit der Ricke oder Geiß. Und der Hirsch ist gern bei seiner Kuh, bzw. Hindin. Darauf wolltest Du zwar nicht hinaus, aber in einem Sprachforum bin ich für korrekte Benennung :)

Comment: @userunknown Regarding Reh and Katzenfutter: I have slight problems following your logic. Nothing I wrote indicate what you are implicating here. I have tried to clarify, but I am honestly not even sure what you didn't understand, so please ask if my edit doesn't solve your issues. Regarding the history of grammatical gender: You can confirm what I wrote in any publication about Proto-Indo-European grammar and grammatical genders. You can start with the Wikipedia articles if you don't have any better material. I suppose that *you* have a source for your theory? Please tell.

Comment: Note this ado about Indo-European does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @DavidVogt In the last two paragraphs, I do answer the question. I should perhaps have started with the answer and continued with the explanation instead of starting with the explanation, which I considered important to understand the answer. I'll change the order of elements.

Comment: "In the North Germanic languages ... there is still remains of a gender-like distinction between animate and inanimate things." Can you give a simple example? I studied some Norwegian and I am not aware of this.

Comment: @Neugierig In Norwegian, for example the third person singular pronoun: 'han' is animate, m - 'hun' is animate, f - 'den' is inanimate, m or f - 'det' is inanimate, n.

Comment: At this point it's clear enough that there's little hope in uncovering the true reason, but speculating about _not implausible_ reasons (the best we can do) is still interesting. I wanted to let you know that I appreciate your answer despite no upvotes from others. I found this blog post (from a reasonable source, a linguist) on the very same topic: https://blog.oup.com/2011/10/wife/  It provides one possible explanation, while admitting that it's just speculation.

Comment: @jarnbjo Thanks, I see what you mean. That kind of distinction is actually pretty common in many languages ("this" for objects, "he" for persons, with both forms coming in multiple grammatical genders).

Comment: @Neugierig My answer actually has 4 upvotes. You can click on the number to get a breakdown of up- and down-votes. I am honestly not quite sure where the down-votes are coming from, but I suspect (and am afraid) that it has become politically incorrect to talk about basic language features, just because they don't fit some kind of gender activist agenda.

Comment: Maybe it is getting downvoted because 80% of the answer has nothing to do with the neuter gender of *Weib*?

Comment: @DavidVogt The rest of the answer explains why it is correct that the word ought to be feminine and the question is legit, contrary to many of the comments and e.g. Hubert's answer, which only tries to explain that the question does not make sense. Without acknowledging the question, it would not make sense to try to answer it. OP commented and appreciated my answer, so it seems obvious that my answer at least addresses what *he* asked about.

Comment: Simply upvoting the question and downvoting answers you find unhelpful would send the same message. You could even ask a new question about the relationship between grammatical and natural gender (and answer it yourself).

Comment: "Fräulein... diminuitive", good note, compare "Weiblein", and especially "das Weibchen" (chiefly of animals), "das Männchen" (also of animals, but used mannequins and other diminutives, sometimes derogative).

Comment: Note that we may observe correspondances of PIE \*gw- to reflexes in *b-*, similar to the irritating, asserted \*kw- > \*p- shift in various words. Could a prefix to the root of *queen* \*gwen- be involved, a wi-queen? I'm not sure where the *-chen* diminutive comes from, a comparison to Russian "-ka" (e.g. Matrioshka) or several unfamiliar languages (Japanese *ke*?) comes to mind, but it might be taken from a model word, that was originally not solely diminutive. Is this it? The name "Wiebke" comes to mind.

Comment: In fact, I think it's the *-en* that often denotes feminine. vgl. dagegen "der Täuberich" u.s.w. (kein besseres Bsp. auf die schnelle gefunden).

Answer (score 5):

Certain things have already been established in other answers, and we have not got very far, so let us see what we have got and where we go next.

Firstly, *Weib* is of unknown origin. Although it has been traced back quite a few centuries in a "womanly" sense, we cannot rule out the possibly that it meant something else before that. But we have nothing to go on to come up with a definitive explanation. The best we can do is to consider what might cause this situation, and see which looks most plausible or has any evidence to support it.

The second thing is that whilst it is true that grammatical gender and biological sex are not the same thing, it is also true that the vast majority of words for females are feminine and the vast majority of words for males are masculine. *Weib* is therefore an exception that it is worth looking for an explanation for.

There are several things that I can think of that could in theory explain such an anomaly.

1. There could have been a semantic shift - that is, the word could originally have meant something else. We simply cannot tell as we do not know where the word came from. However, I can give an example of a word in another language. [*Boireannach* /bɔrʲənəx/](https://www.faclair.com/index.aspx?Language=en) is the Scots Gaelic for a woman but is masculine. The usual explanation for this is that it was the neuter form of an adjective meaning "female" and was used as a noun meaning "something female". There is a corresponding word *fireannach* /firʲənəx/ meaning "man". But then two things happened. Firstly we lost our neuter and almost all neuter nouns became masculine. This does not concern us here. The second is that society changed and a new, general-purpose word for a woman was needed, where before there had been maidens and wives, regarded as separate categories, and with no over-arching term. Thus, at its simplest, this anomaly was caused by a change in the meaning of a word.
2. Changing view of what female means. We have a fairly biological definition of female, but in the past, would someone who was not married or ready for marriage, who had not had sex and who had not developed adult female characteristics be regarded as female? Before you were old enough for marriage you were a Mädchen, essentially asexual and thus neuter, and then, when you were only just reaching physical maturity (with younger marriage and older puberty than today), you would marry, become a Frau and thus be regarded as a functional female. It is noticeable that several of the examples quoted in other answers are for females or people of unspecified gender that would not have reached sexual maturity: *das Fräulein*, *das Kind*, *das Mädchen*, *das Baby* (which is often "it" even in English). To add an example from another language, we have Greek [τέκνον](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dte%2Fknon) (teknon) which is a neuter word for a child. It is difficult to see how this could explain the gender of *Weib* but we cannot rule it out as we do not know the origin.
3. Origin in a genderless language. One possibility, since we do not know the origin of the three-gender system in Proto-Indo-European, is that all neuter words in PIE come from one language, and all masculine and feminine words come from another.

These are the possibilites as I see them. If anyone can add any others, or provide any arguments as to which might be relevant to *Weib*, please do.

Comment: Der Junge/der Bub sind auch nicht geschlechtsreif. Das überzeugt mich nicht. Kinder und Babys sind nicht geschlechtslos - der Säugling ist auch wieder generisch männlich. Außerdem steht die Frage, selbst wenn sich die Urstprünge für "das Weib" in der Geschichte verlieren, im Raum, wieso sich das Geschlecht dann nicht angepasst hat, im Laufe der Zeit. Das Laptop ist auch zu dem Laptop geworden, inzwischen.

Comment: Interesting example from Scottish Gaelic. This kind of _possible mechanism_ is the next best thing I was looking for if (as it seems to be the case) the origin of the word can't be traced back far enough to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Yes @userunknown, this shows that the situation is complicated. It also seems to be the case that in our culture there is much more of a category change for females than for males. German, French and English all had a Frau/Fräulein distinction but no corresponding distinction. It is these Fräulein that are most prone to being considered neuter. It is almost as if the three genders corresponded to. Herr/Frau/Fräulein. No wonder they got rid of the Fräulein and mademoiselles.

Comment: It's true that Mädchen and Fräulein are neuter, but so are Bübchen and Männlein.  These words are newer than Weib, too. So they do not support your second point, that non-breeding females might be considered neuter (especially since one meaning of Weib is "wife"). On the other hand, the point about changing meanings, with the Gaelic example, is interesting and relevant.

Comment: About your 3rd point: The details of the PIE gender system's origin might not be fully understood, but we have some pretty good ideas about the general development. Most likely it goes back to an animacy based system to which a third gender was later added by reinterpreting collective nouns. See [this Linguistics SE question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/525/what-is-the-origin-of-non-natural-grammatical-genders-in-indo-european-languages) for details.

Comment: Thank you, @marcschütz. That is indeed a possibility and is interesting. I was just listing some others. However, I have never been very convinced by arguments based on PIE having evolved in isolation without interaction with other languages. In the specific case of the neuter I see what could be interpreted as not having cases of its own and thus potentially coming from a different language.

Comment: What I am referring to is the fact that all neuter nouns I know in German and other languages only have one form in the singular, one in the dual (if in use) and one in the plural with *everything* else being borrowed from the masculine. This is consistent with the neuter coming from a language that does not have cases as we know them.

Comment: @userunknown Der Bube in meinem Kartenspiel sieht durchaus geschlechtsreif aus, ebenso wie der Laufbursche zumindest in Arbeit steht. Der bayerische *Bub* ist etwas anderes, kann man so sagen. Der *-ling* egal welcher Art ist immer generisch maskulin. Das Gegenstück, wenngleich eventuell späterer machart, ist die *-liene*, nicht wahr? Da die Frage so schon kompliziert genug ist, hilft es nicht, weitere Haare an den Beispielen herbeizuziehen.

Comment: @Vectory: Das leichte Mädchen ist sicher nicht asexuell und umgekehrt sind die Katze oder die Gabel nicht sexuell. Es ist ein Irrweg, sexuelles Geschlecht mit sprachlichem verbunden zu sehen. Die ~liene ist auch kein Gegenstück (Zwilliene? Flüchtliene?) zum ~ling. Was ist ein Praling?

Answer (score 3):

From other answers, it is clear now that the true reason is lost in the mists of time. It is still interesting (and linguistically useful) to speculate about *not completely implausible* reasons, so we can get an idea of how this might happen at all. ([David Robinson](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50146/36583) shows one not-so-obvious way how a similar gender-mismatch came about in Scottish Gaelic.)

I found a blog post by [Anatoly Liberman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Liberman), a linguist, on the very same topic:

[Were ancient ‘wives’ women?](https://blog.oup.com/2011/10/wife/)

I will quote the relevant paragraph, while noting that the author himself makes it clear that this is mere speculation.

> Among the Old Scandinavian goddesses, we find *Sif*.  Her name, derived from Indo-European *si-bh*, is related to Engl. *sib* and Latin *su-us* “one’s own.”  Sif must have been the patroness of family ties.  The only recorded myth in which she plays a visible role, points to fertility, rather than affinity by marriage, but the concepts of family and fertility are close.  I compared *Sib* and the personal pronoun *we*.  The protoform of *we* was *wis* (with “long *i*, that is, *wees*, if spelled in today’s English); *-s* was an ending.  I think that Old Germanic *wibh*, the protoform of *wife*, was *wi-bh* a formation parallel to *sibh*.  If I am right, sibh meant “all the people related by marriage,” while *wibh* referred to a group tracing its origin to the same woman.  It was a word like *y’all*.  *Wibh*, as I see it, had to be neuter, because it was the name of a community whose members descended or believed that they had descended from the same woman.  It included both males and females, and in Germanic, when a pronoun like *they* covered “mixed company,” the form was always neuter (John and Jack needed the masculine they, Betty and Mary would be covered by the feminine *they*, whereas Jack and Jill required the neuter *they*).  As time went on, the word meaning “we, descendants of one woman” came to mean “woman.”  Wife emerged as a term of social relations, but the old grammatical gender remained.  The old Indo-European word for “woman” (preserved by Engl. *quean*) also survived, but it narrowed its sphere of application and came to denote “woman in her biological (child bearing) function.”

Comment: No. Speculations on a faulty premise doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is a part of the German speaking area, where [women have the neuter grammatical gender](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/artikelform/). This area stretches from the South-Western fringe (Switzerland, Alsace, Lorraine, Saarland, and then makes a turn towards the centre of today's Germany. Maybe the word *Weib* got its meaning and gender in a part of this area and spread out from there.

Comment: interesting.... Do you know, whether people in areas where _das/es Anna_ is used, also say _das/es Frau (vom Peter)_ , _das/es Lehrerin_  or similar? Or is this restricted to 'neuter article + given name'?

Comment: There are still grammatically feminine words in that area, including *Frau*, *Freundin*, *Lehrerin*. However, the usual expression for *Peters Frau* in Saarland is *dem Peter seins* (without using the word *Frau* at all).

Comment: Wer sich nach mehr Daten sehnt, der könnte sich folgenden Artikel zu Gemüte führen: Nübling, Damaris/Busley, Simone/Drenda, Juliane (2013): Dat Anna und s Eva – Neutrale Frauenrufnamen in deutschen Dialekten und im Luxemburgischen zwischen pragmatischer und semantischer Genuszuweisung. In: Zeitschrift für Dialektologie und Linguistik 80/2, 152-196.

Comment: Im übrigen wird es wohl andersherum sein: Die Frauennamen können regional mit neutralem Artikel stehen, weil es Nomen wie *Weib* und *Mädchen* gibt.

Comment: @DavidVogt ... alternatively, it was "diminutive first" and then the neuter gender became a hypochorism marker even for non-diminutive name forms.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you always should be aware of two facts:

1. Grammatical gender is a property of a noun (i.e. of a word). It is not a property of the thing that is named with this noun.
2. The biological sex of a person and the grammatical gender of a word that is used to name this person are different things.

---

### An example for #1:

The English word *"car"* can be translated in may ways into German. The possible translations are not perfect synonyms, but when we are are talking about a rusty old limousine you can translate *»the car«* (which has no gender at all in English) in these three ways into German:

- > Das Auto

  This is a neuter noun and it is the standard translation for *"car".*
- > Der Wagen

  This is a masculine noun and it means literal *"the carriage"* but is often used for bigger cars like limousines.
- > Die Karre

  This is a feminine noun and it is used for shabby old cars.

So, while these nouns have three different grammatical genders, they still can be used as names for the very same car.

---

### Other examples for #2:

- > Das Mädchen

  This is also a neuter noun, and it means *girl*. It is a diminutive, and in German all diminutives are neuter.
- > Das Fräulein

  Again a diminutive that was used for young ladies. It is outdated and considered not to be politically correct anymore.
- > Die Tunte

  This is a female noun used for some men (la-di-da gay man)
- > Das Kind

  Meaning: *Child*. It is a neuter noun, but is used for persons who may be male or female.
- > Das Baby

  Meaning: *Baby, toddler*. Same as before.

Comment: You should also be aware of the fact that there is a very strong correlation in all Indo-European languages between biological sex and grammatical gender for all words naming an animate subject of a specific sex. It is also commonly assumed that the split between the masculine and feminine grammatical genders, which goes back to Proto-Indo-European, origins in differences in biological sex.

Comment: @jarnbjo: While I mostly agree with your comment, it kind of reads as if you were claiming the masculine/feminine distinction to be basal to all Indo-European languages. If I'm not mistaken, the generally (though not universally) accepted consensus is that PIE originally had only a common/neuter (or animate/inanimate) distinction, with the three-way masculine/feminine/neuter system evolving only later, some time after the Anatolian languages like Hittite had branched off from the rest of the Indo-European family.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, it is commonly assumed that PIE originally only had an animate/inanimate distinction and at some point, the animate 'gender' split into masculine and feminine. I am not sure if there is a general consensus on *when* that happened, but I thought it was assumed to happen during or even in the early PIE period. The Wikipedia article on PIE only describes the three-gender system and does not mention animate/inanimate at all. Sanskrit, which dates back to the same period as Hittite, already had three genders.

Comment: Car ist im Englischen nicht geschlechtslos. "The car is broken. He/she/it had an accident." Mir fällt da die Entscheidung leicht, und das bedeutet doch, dass ein Geschlecht vorliegt, oder?

Comment: @userunknown: Das Nomen »the car« hat kein Geschlecht, weil im Englischen kein einziges Nomen ein Geschlecht hat. Die Wörter, die im Englischen ein Geschlecht haben, sind ausschließlich die Pronomen. *»He«* hat ein Geschlecht, *»she«* auch, ebenso *»it«, »him«, »her«, »its«, »his«* und *»hers«*. Fertig. Mehr als diese  acht Wörter mit einem grammatischen Geschlecht gibt es im Englischen nicht. Und im Englischen gibt es auch keine Geschlechter-Kongruenz zwischen einem Pronomen und dem Nomen auf das sich das Pronomen bezieht.

Comment: Das sieht man z.B. an Berufsbezeichnungen. Welches Geschlecht hat deiner Meinung nach das Wort *»the teacher«*? Wäre es ein männliches Wort, müsste man immer mit »he« darauf verweisen, wäre es weiblich, müsste man immer »she« sagen. In Wahrheit hängt im englischen aber das grammatische Geschlecht des Pronomens vom biologischen Geschlecht der mit dem Nomen bezeichneten Person ab. Und wenn sich ein Pronomen auf etwas anderes als eine Person bezieht, ist es immer sächlich. (ausgenommen Haustiere, Schiffe, ...)

Comment: As written in the original question, I am well aware that generally grammatical gender and meaning are independent. But as @jarnbjo says, this is not so for most words that explicitly imply sex (Mann/Frau, Stier/Kuh, Junge, Magd, etc.). You can't deny that Weib being neuter is very unusual, and worthy of investigation. None of the examples you brought indicate sex explicitly *and* lack an obvious explanation for their gender a the same time (the diminutive suffix is an obvious explanation that I already mentioned in the question).

Comment: This answer does not at all address the question.

Comment: Many English names retain morphemic markers of gender. "-ia" is in my mind a typical marker of female names. Whereas "-er" is often masculine in German (indeed it's der *Karren*), and at least the morpheme is retained in English, even if the association has been lost. I suspect such morphemes influence the phonology of articles in the environment of very short words, however, whether that's true or not does not matter here, because English wasn't really in question.

Comment: Also cf. *actress* vs *actor* and the like

Comment: “Das Fräulein” was not used for *young* women, but for *unmarried* women. Which is why it is considered politically incorrect.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "Der Lehrer hat das Klassenbuch zu führen. Dort trägt er die Unterrichtsinhalte ein." - Wie würdest Du das übersetzen und welches Geschlecht hat also "teacher", wenn kein spezifischer Teacher addressiert wird, dem man in die Hose schauen könnte? Oder ist das gar nicht übersetzbar und die englischsprachige Welt würde von Grund auf anders formulieren?