# Bestimmt das Geschlecht des Wortes das Fürwort?

Tags: gender, pronoun

Wird das richtige Fürwort in einem Satz jemals bestimmt von dem Geschlecht des Wortes des Objekts, von dem die Rede ist?

Zum Beispiel, sage ich „**Es** lacht vor Freude“ wenn von einem Kind die Rede ist, da das Wort *Kind* geschlechtslos sei, auch wenn bekannt ist,  dass dieses Kind ein Junge ist?

Oder: sage ich „**Sie** schläft ruhig“ wenn von einer Katze die Rede ist, da das Wort *Katze* weiblich ist, auch wenn bekannt ist, dass die Katze männlich ist?

Das kann sicherlich nicht stimmen, denn dann müsste ich sagen „**Er** ist kaputt“ wenn ich von einem Tisch rede, denn *Tisch* ist männlich, oder irre ich mich mit diesem Argument?

Comment: *Das kann sicherlich nicht stimmen, denn dann müsste ich sagen “Er ist kaputt” wenn ich von einem Tisch rede, denn “Tisch” ist männlich,* - Warum genau kann das Deiner Meinung nach nicht stimmen? Warum glaubst Du, "Er ist kaputt" wäre falsch?

Comment: *Er ist kaputt* ist die einzig richtige Formulierung, wenn man von einem Tisch spricht.

Comment: Es hängt davon ab, mit welchem Begriff zuvor Bezug genommen wurde. "Das ist ein schönes Möbel." "Es ist aber leider kaputt." vs.  "Das ist ein schöner Tisch." "Er ist aber leider kaputt."  "Das ist eine schöne Handwerksarbeit." "Sie ...".

Comment: Eine männliche Katze ist ein Kater. Kater = Er, Katze = Sie.

Comment: Es hängt wohl stark vom Sprachraum ab, ob "Er [= ein Tisch] ist kaputt" akzeptabel ist oder nicht. In meinem Umfeld Berlin/Brandenburg ist es ganz und garnicht üblich, sicherlich weil "er" eine Persönlichkeit impliziert. Hier wird immer distal "der" bzw. bei einfachen Worten die ganze Phrase "der Tisch" Verwendung finden. Darunter wäre pronominal "Das" für Personen widerum unüblich, "Es" hilfsweise, bevorzugt, "die/Sie" zumindest für Mädchen zu bevorzugen.

Comment: @Polygnome: "Katze" ist generisches Femininum für Katzen allgemein, wenn das Geschlecht nicht interessiert, wie "Bäcker" für den Beruf derer, die backen, männlich ist. Wenn davor vom Kater als der Katze die Rede war, was sehr üblich ist, dann muss es bei "sie" bleiben, auch wenn bekannt ist, dass die Katze männlichen Geschlechts ist, denn das sprachliche Geschlecht ist nicht das biologische, noch weniger ist es Geschlechtsrolle (Gender).

Comment: @Vectory Ich finde, du solltest das als Antwort schreiben – in der Umgangssprache wird ein Tisch ja kaum "er" genannt, sondern "der", wie du sagst.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das Fürwort richtet sich immer nach dem **grammatikalischem Geschlecht**.

> **Das Mädchen** spielt mit den Ritterfiguren. **Es** möchte später selbst Ritter werden.

> **Die Katze** schläft auf dem Sofa. Es ist **ihr** Lieblingsplatz. Neben ihr liegt **der Kater**. Es ist auch **sein** Lieblingsplatz.

> **Der** Tisch im Wohnzimmer ist kaputt. **Er** ist gestern zusammengebrochen.

Comment: It does not take much to continue sentences with *Mädchen* (whose gender is a constant source of confusion for non-native speakers) with *sie*: "Das Mädchen auf dem Foto heißt Sabine. Hier spielt sie mit ihrer Lieblingspuppe." It is formally a grammatical error but after "Sabine" most people would not take issue if a casual speaker continued with the more natural feminine pronoun.

Comment: Why would this be an error. The sie clearly refers to Sabine and not das Mädchen.

Comment: Hm. It didn't occur to me that that's possible. May be. I tried to make the case that native German speakers may switch grammatically incorrectly to *sie* when the subject referred to still was the grammatical neutral *Mädchen.* Perhaps my example does not illustrate that because *Sabine* can be considered having a gender, too.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica A more suitable example might be "Das Mädchen dort schiebt ihr Fahrrad nach Hause". While correctly it should be of course "schiebt sein Fahrrad".

Comment: Yes, that is the most direct example, but then the dissonance from the grammatical error is also strongest. I tried to smooth it by using the personal pronoun only in the next sentence and inserting a distraction, but as you said *Sabine* has a gender ("diese Sabine ist aber dumm!"), so the female pronoun can (and should) be read to relate to her.

Comment: Überall außer im Ruhrgebiet: "Dat Sabine hat jetzt Abitur".

Comment: [Constructio ad sensum](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructio_ad_sensum).

Comment: It is incorrect to say that constructions like _Das Mädchen spielt mit den Ritterfiguren. __Sie__ möchte später selbst Ritter werden._ would be wrong. Seeing this as grammatically wrong is just not grasping the underlying mechanisms here: The grammatical referent is changing, while its extension (the person referred to) is still the same. That's a very common construction and any grammar declaring this as wrong is just incomplete. I am giving this a -1 because this is not reflected in the answer.

Comment: Do you have *any* reference for that? What about this construction: "Ich kenne die Person! Er geht immer bei mir einkaufen."

Comment: Duden-Grammatik, 8. Aufl., Randnr. 1591, S. 1001.

Answer (score 6):

In der Regel und in fast allen Fällen richtet sich das Pronomen tatsächlich nach dem grammatikalischen Geschlecht des Wortes, das es ersetzt. Alle Beispiele, die infinitezero nennt, sind grammatikalisch völlig korrekt und werden so im Alltag verwendet.

> Warum liegt da ein Stein?
> Weiß ich nicht. Jemand hat **ihn** da hingelegt.

Wenn es bei Tieren geschlechtsspezifische Wörter gibt, wird oft auf die »Grundform« zurückgegriffen: *Katze* schlägt *Kater*, *Hund* schlägt *Hündin*, *Ziege* schlägt *Ziegenbock* und *Kuh* schlägt in meinen Augen *Ochse* oder *Stier* (obwohl das Grundwort wohl eher *Rind* wäre).

> *zeigt auf eine Katze* Schau mal, sie hat eine Maus gefangen.
> *zeigt auf einen Hund* Und er schläft immer noch.

Allerdings: Wenn man *weiß*, dass es sich bei einer bestimmten Katze um einen Kater handelt, kann man durchaus sofort *er* nehmen, ohne dass man vorher den Kater (also das Wort) explizit nennen muss. Gleiches gilt für *Hündin*, weswegen bei mir daheim eher *sie* als *er* verwendet wurde, wenn es um den Hund ging.

Davon ist auch das Wort *Mädchen* betroffen. Grammatikalisch ist es ein Neutrum, daher wäre *es* grammatikalisch angebracht und wird vor allem in älterer Literatur ausschließlich verwendet – manchmal und [in gewissen Dialekten](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/artikelform/) auch wenn das Mädchen mit Namen genannt wird. Heutzutage ist es aber oft üblich, für *Mädchen* das Pronomen *sie* zu verwenden.

> Da drüben sitzen ein Junge und ein Mädchen. Er trägt Lederhosen, sie trägt Dirndl.

> Ich hab ein kleines Mädchen auf dem Spielplatz gesehen. Sie war vielleicht fünf Jahre alt.

Comment: Good observation that adhering to the grammatical gender of *Mädchen* may undergo a change over time. After you said that, using the neutral pronoun seemed indeed a bit stiff and correct, perhaps old-fashioned.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn eine Sprache über grammatische Geschlechter verfügt, hängen diese grammatischen Geschlechter nur sehr lose mit den biologischen Geschlechtern von Personen und anderen Lebewesen zusammen. Insbesondere hängt das grammatische Geschlecht vom Wort ab, das eine Sache bezeichnet, und nicht von der bezeichneten Sache selbst.

Ein gutes Beispiel sind die drei Wörter *»Auto«, »Karre«* und *»Wagen«*:

- **das Auto** (grammatisches Geschlecht: sächlich)
  Ein Auto ist mehrspuriges Fahrzeug, das von einem Motor angetrieben wird und der Beförderung von Personen dient.
- **die Karre** (grammatisches Geschlecht: weiblich)
  Eine Karre ist ursprünglich ein einfaches Gestell mit Rädern, ohne eigenen Antrieb, das verwendet wurde um Lasten zu transportieren. Das Wort wird aber auch verwendet, um schäbige alte Autos zu bezeichnen, die entweder gerade noch fahrtüchtig sind, oder die sogar schon so kaputt sind, dass sie gar nicht mehr verwendbar sind.
- **der Wagen** (grammatisches Geschlecht: männlich)
  Ein Wagen war ursprünglich ein Fahrzeug, das von Pferden gezogen wurde, und mit dem Personen oder Lasten transportiert wurden. Dieses Wort wurde früher ganz allgemein als Synonym für *»Auto«* verwendet, heute bezeichnet man mit dem Wort *»Wagen«* aber eher größere Limousinen, also eher etwas teurere Autos.

Wenn nun ein großes Auto, das bei seiner Anschaffung sehr teuer war, 20 oder 30 Jahre lang nicht gepflegt wurde, und nun in einem so schlechten Zustand ist, dass es kaum noch fahrtüchtig ist, dann kann man dieses Fahrzeug mit allen drei Wörtern bezeichnen, und muss dafür unterschiedliche grammatische Geschlechter verwenden:

> - **Das Auto** steht in der Garage. **Es** ist groß, alt und schäbig.
> - **Die Karre** steht in der Garage. **Sie** ist groß, alt und schäbig.
> - **Der Wagen** steht in der Garage. **Er** ist groß, alt und schäbig.

Beachte, dass in allen drei Sätzen von genau derselben Sache die Rede ist. Das grammatische Geschlecht hängt nicht von der Sache ab, sondern von dem Substantiv, das man verwendet um es zu benennen.

---

### Das gilt auch für Personen!

Prinzipiell folgt das grammatische Geschlecht in den meisten Fällen schon dem biologischen Geschlecht. Das ist aber nur deswegen der Fall, weil die meisten Substantive, mit denen man Personen bezeichnet, üblicherweise ein grammatisches Geschlecht haben, das mit dem biologischen Geschlecht der Person übereinstimmt:

- Substantive, die biologisch weibliche Personen bezeichnen:

  - die Frau (grammatisch weiblich)
  - die Dame (grammatisch weiblich)
  - die Mutter (grammatisch weiblich)
  - die Tochter (grammatisch weiblich)
- Substantive, die biologisch männliche Personen bezeichnen:

  - der Mann (grammatisch männlich)
  - der Herr (grammatisch männlich)
  - der Vater (grammatisch männlich)
  - der Sohn (grammatisch männlich)

Die Regeln der Grammatik (welcher Artikel, welches Pronomen usw.) richten sich aber ausschließlich nach dem grammatischen Geschlecht dieses Substantivs. Das biologische Geschlecht spielt dabei keine Rolle. Es gibt aber auch Wörter, die zur Bezeichnung von Personen verwendet werden, bei denen das grammatische Geschlecht des Wortes nicht mit dem biologischen Geschlecht der bezeichneten Person übereinstimmt:

- Substantive, die biologisch weibliche Personen bezeichnen:

  - das Mädchen (grammatisch sächlich)
    <sub>*Das Wort »Mädchen« ist ein Diminutiv, also ein Verkleinerungswort. Das erkennt man an der Endsilbe »-chen«. Alle deutschen Diminutive sind immer sächlich. Das ist eine der wenigen Regeln, für die es keine einzige Ausnahme gibt.*</sub>
  - das Weib (grammatisch sächlich)
    <sub>*Vom Wort »Weib« leitet sich das Adjektiv »weiblich« ab, trotzdem ist dieses Wort selbst sächlich.*</sub>
  - der Trampel (grammatisch männlich)
    <sub>*Das Wort »Trampel« ist ein in Österreich (möglicherweise auch in Bayern) geläufiges Schimpfwort, mit dem man besonders ungeschickte und gedankenlose Frauen bezeichnet. Es wird ausschließlich für Frauen und Mädchen verwendet, und ist trotzdem grammatisch männlich.*</sub>
- Substantive, die biologisch männliche Personen bezeichnen:

  - die Tunte (grammatisch weiblich)
    <sub>*Bezeichnung für einen Mann, der entweder Frauenkleider trägt, oder sich sonst besonders weiblich verhält. Das Wort wird meist (aber nicht immer) abwertend verwendet.*</sub>
- Substantive, die sowohl für biologisch weibliche als auch männliche Personen verwendet werden können:

  - das Baby (grammatisch sächlich)
  - das Kind (grammatisch sächlich)
  - die Person (grammatisch weiblich)
  - das Genie (grammatisch sächlich)

Wie gesagt, richten sich die grammatischen Regeln nach dem grammatischen Geschlecht, nicht nach dem biologischen. Man kann ein und dieselbe Frau als *»Frau«, »Weib«* oder *»Trampel«* bezeichnen:

> Schau dir **diese Frau** an! **Sie** macht alles kaputt!
> Schau dir **dieses Weib** an! **Es** macht alles kaputt!
> Schau dir **diesen Trampel** an! **Er** macht alles kaputt!

Aber natürlich auch der Klassiker:

> Siehst du **das Mädchen** dort drüben? **Es** ist meine Tochter.

---

### Eine wichtige Ausnahme

Zu ergänzen ist, dass es für Personen eine Ausnahme gibt, die früher (vor 50 oder 100 Jahren) noch eher selten verwendet wurde, heute aber durchaus üblich und somit korrekt ist:

Wenn ein sächliches oder männliches Wort verwendet wird um eine biologisch weibliche Person zu bezeichnen, darf man auch weibliche Pronomen verwenden. Folgende Sätze sind also ebenfalls korrekt (es gibt in diesen Fällen also zwei korrekte Möglichkeiten):

> Schau dir **dieses Weib** an! **Sie** macht alles kaputt!
> Schau dir **diesen Trampel** an! **Sie** macht alles kaputt!
> Siehst du **das Mädchen** dort drüben? **Sie** ist meine Tochter.

Das gilt auch für biologisch männliche Personen:

> Erkennen Sie **die Person,** die Sie überfallen hat? - Ja, es ist **die** zweite von links.
> Erkennen Sie **die Person,** die Sie überfallen hat? - Ja, es ist **der** zweite von links.
>
> **Die Tunte** trägt ein rosarotes Kleid. **Sie** fällt damit auf.
> **Die Tunte** trägt ein rosarotes Kleid. **Er** fällt damit auf.

---

### Ein ganz besonderes Beispiel: Das Heidi

Die Schweizerin Johanna Spyri (1827–1901) hat in den Jahren 1880 und 1881 die beiden Kinderbücher *»Heidis Lehr- und Wanderjahre«* und *»Heidi kann brauchen, was es gelernt hat«* geschrieben. Diese beiden Romane wurden 1974 von japanischen Zeichnern zur weltweit bekannten Zeichentrickserie *»Heidi«* verarbeitet, und sie wurden mittlerweile bereits zwölfmal verfilmt. Hier sind einige wörtlichen Zitate aus dem Roman:

> - **Das Heidi** und die Geißen hüpften und sprangen fröhlich neben ihm her.
> - Wie er nun den Schrank aufgemacht hatte, kam **das Heidi** schnell heran ... Nun sah **es** sich aufmerksam um in dem Raum ...
> - ... und **das Heidi** lief hintendrein, ... **es** konnte da nicht zurückbleiben.
> - Da rannte **das Heidi** schnell wieder zurück ... und dann sprang **es** mitten in die davonziehende Herde hinein.

Das Heidi ist in beiden Romanen ganz konsequent immer sächlich, obwohl Heidi natürlich ein biologisch weibliches Kind ist. Aber Heidi ist eben ein Kind (**das** Kind = sächlich) bzw. ein fünfjähriges Mädchen (**das** Mädchen = sächlich). Und aus diesem Grund sind in fast allen Schweizer Dialekten die Namen kleiner Mädchen nicht weiblich, sondern sächlich. Und gerade in der Schweiz haben die Dialekte einen besonders großen Einfluss auf die Umgangssprache und somit auch auf die schweizerische Standardsprache.

Verlegt wurde der Roman übrigens in Gotha, im deutschen Thüringen, nahe der geographischen Mitte Deutschlands, vom Verlag *Friedrich Andreas Perthes.* Und auch dort hielt man es um 1880 offenbar noch für korrekt, *»**das** Heidi«* statt *»**die** Heidi«* zu schreiben.

Heute gilt das aber nicht mehr.

Aber sowohl heute wie damals gilt, dass das Geschlecht des Pronomens dem Geschlecht des Substantivs folgt. (Mit der oben erwähnten relativ jungen Ausnahme für Personen.)

Comment: Die "Ausnahme", wenn es denn eine ist, ist definitiv älter als 50 Jahre. Ein Beleg aus *Effi Briest* hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/50464/35111

Comment: @DavidVogt: Der Satz von Fontane beginnt mit einem *»es«*, das sich auf das Mädchen bezieht: *»**Es** war ein sehr hübsches Mädchen, was selbst unsere Offiziere – wir hatten nämlich Offiziere, noch dazu rote Husaren – auch immer fanden, und verstand sich dabei sehr gut auf Toilette, schwarzes Sammetmieder und eine Blume, Rose oder auch Heliotrop, und wenn **sie** nicht so vorstehende große Augen gehabt hätte ...«* ...

Comment: ... Zwischen dem Wort *»Mädchen«* und dem Pronomen *»sie«* stehen 34 andere Wörter. Über diese lange Strecke verblasst das sächliche Substantiv im Kontext und wird durch das (wortlose) Bild einer weiblichen Person ersetzt. Das hervorgehobene *»sie«* bezieht sich nicht mehr auf das Wort, sondern auf dieses wortlose weibliche Bild. Denn Dinge im Kontext, auf die sich Pronomen beziehen, müssen nicht immer durch konkrete Worte bezeichnet sein.

Comment: ... Beispiel: Zwei Jugendliche warten auf den Bus. Eine ältere Frau mit einem auffallend großen Hut geht vorbei. Dialog zwischen den Jugendlichen: *»Hast du **die** gesehen?« - »Ja, **die** hat einen Hut, den würde nicht mal meine Oma mehr aufsetzen.«* Ein Substantiv, das die Hutträgerin bezeichnen würde, kam in der gesamten Konversation niemals vor, es gibt lediglich zweimal das Pronomen *»die«*, das sich auf eine weibliche Person im Kontext bezieht, die aber niemals konkret bezeichnet wurde. Das Wort *»sie«* in dem Satz aus Effi Briest funktioniert auf genau dieselbe Weise.

Comment: Das stimmt alles, aber die Frage ist, ob man "Ausnahme" und "50 Jahre" so stehen lassen sollte. Ein Beleg von Th. Storm mit sehr kurzer Entfernung: *Da zog das Mädchen **ihr** rotes Händchen aus dem Muff, und ihn zu sich ziehend, wies **sie** mit dem Finger nach dem Vogelbauer.*

Comment: @DavidVogt: Das überzeugt mich schon mehr. Ich habe den Satz nun anders formuliert.

Comment: Ist Heidi vielleicht einfach ein Diminutiv?

Comment: @CarstenS: Nein. Wie ich schon sagte, gilt das generell für Mädchennamen von kleinen Kindern. Es wäre auch "das Adelheid", jedoch wird der Name "Adelheid" im Roman nur in der direkten Rede (von Fräulein Rottenmeier) verwendet, also niemals mit Artikel. Und das Fräulein Klara ist bereits 12 Jahre alt, also zu alt um noch in die Kategorie "kleines Kind" zu fallen, daher wird "die Klara" immer mit weiblichen Artikel verwendet.

Answer (score -1):

In der Regel wird sich die Wahl des Wortes nach dem grammatischen Geschlecht richten. Bei natürlichem Geschlecht is die Wahl offensichtlich, "Das Mädchen, ... sie ..." wenn gleich in einigen Gegenden generell "das" auch für Frauen Verwendung finden mag ("Das Sabine") und auch "Es" also landläufig zu finden ist. In der Regel ist gegen Übereinstimmen des grammatischen Genus zwischen Subjekt und referentiellem Pronomen auch formal nichts einzuwenden. Es wird aber förmlich schwierig "Er" auf eine Frau zu beziehen, soweit gewöhnliche Nomen oft maskulin sind.

> Sowas habe ich selten gesehen: Der Schornsteinfeger war eine Frau.

Das Fürwort würde sich hier regelmäßig auf das nähste Nomen, *eine Frau*, beziehen. Selbst wenn hochgestochen ein attributives adjektiv steht, "... ist weiblich", würde niemals nie "Er" folgen. "Sie" gilt dann ggf. nicht als referentielles Fürwort, sondern demonstrativ, das Geschlecht darstellend.

Folglich wird man geneigt sein anders zu formulieren, "Schornsteinfegerin". Auch bei anderen Nomen mag es eine Wahl geben: "der Strauch" oder "das Gewächs". In der Regel, außer in höchst förmlichen Texten wo es um Genauigkeit geht, wird sonst nichts dagegen einzuwenden sein, Dinge durcheg als "das" zu bezeichnen: "Das ist aber komisch, der Strauch da. Der blüht blau."

So

Comment: 1. Eine Schornsteinfegerin, die keine Frau war, habe ich noch nie gesehen. 2. Noch grotesker ist es, die fehlleitende Bezeichnung des sprachlichen Geschlechts mit "sächlich" so ernst zu nehmen, dass aus dem  Hammer jetzt ein das Hammer wird, nur um die Bezeichnung sächlich nachträglich zu rechtfertigen. Bei Deinem Beispiel mit dem, was komisch ist, ist es aber ein hinweisendes "das", kein Artikel. "Das ist meine Familie, das ist mein Vater, das meine Mutter, das dritte ihr zweites Kind."

Comment: Ja eben, sagte ich doch, "demonstrativ".

Comment: @user-unknown, 1. dass das generische Geschlecht noch immer das generische Geschlecht ist, dürfte dir nicht entgangen sein. 2. Was ist das für ein Strohmann? *Der Hamma* ist kraftvoll, animalisch, oder zumindest wirkungsvoll, sowie ganz und gar nicht abstrakt. Sprachhistorisch ist der m. Genus durchaus nachvollziehbar. "Es Kind"? Vielleicht. Kontrovers ist aber "er/sie" rein anthropomorph: "... weil die Dusche zu mir hält. Sie ist der einzige Freund, den ich noch habe auf der Welt" (Farin Urlaub, *Dusche*). Ich zeigte doch nur, was ich für legitim halte: "[f.] Die Dusche ist [m.] mein Freund".

Comment: Ich verstehe beide Einwände nicht. Was soll "Es Kind"? Das Kind/ein Kind. Der Hammer ist nicht kraftvoll und vor allem nicht animalisch aber selbst wenn? Ist der Löffel kraftvoll/animalisch? Oder der Herr Kant? "Kontrovers ist aber "er/sie" rein anthropomorph". Das ist nicht kontrovers, sondern falsch.