# Haben Babys Geschlecht oder sind sie neutral?

Tags: usage, gender

Wenn ich über ein weibliches Baby schreibe/spreche, sollte ich die Pronomen "**es**" oder "**sie**" benutzen?

Was ich wissen möchte, ist, wenn ich zum Beispiel sagen möchte: "When the baby is 2 she should be walking", schreibe ich: "Wenn das Baby 2 ist, sollte es" oder "sie laufen"?

Auf Englisch fühle ich mich sehr komisch, wenn ich mich auf jemandes Baby beziehe mit "es".

Comment: Nope. What I want to know is, if I want to say, for instance, "When the baby is 2 she should be walking," do I write, "Wenn das Baby 2 ist, sollte es, " or, "sie spazieren?"

Comment: Bitte verfasse den Titel und den Korpus deiner Frage in derselben Sprache. Wenn der Titel auf English und der Korpus auf Deutsch ist, weiß man nicht, in welcher Sprache die Frage verfasst wurde (was noch das kleinere Übel ist), aber man weiß dann auch nicht, in welcher Sprache man Kommentare und Antworten verfassen soll.

Comment: Die Frage im Titel geht übrigens von einer falschen Prämisse aus. Du gehts offenbar davon aus, dass nur "männlich" und "weiblich" Geschlechter sind. Tatsächlich ist aber "sächlich" ebenfalls ein grammatikalisches Geschlecht. Deutsche Substantive haben **IMMER** ein Geschlecht. In Ausnahmefällen kann es sogar vorkommen, dass ein Substantiv mehrere Geschlechter hat: https://german.stackexchange.com/a/49434/1487

Comment: Please add your specific example into your question. And yes, please decide for one language.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast deswegen sollten wir lieber Latein verwenden :) Menschliche Substantive haben sowohl ein Sexus als auch ein Genus, die nicht übereinstimmen müssen. Gegenstände haben kein Sexus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, to rephrase your question (for the sake of my answer, not because you were unclear): Of the two determinants of pronoun choice (natural sex versus grammatical gender of referent noun), which one 'wins'? One rule that I have been told is that if the child's name has been used and even if the name is not sex-specific, then you are entitled henceforth to use the corresponding gender pronoun. E.g.

> *Das Baby heißt Peter. **Er** ist 6 Monate alt.*

I suppose this works because the masculine pronoun is understood to refer to the name (in this instance "Peter") rather than to the noun *das Baby*. The same is true of other neuter nouns that refer to people like *das Kind* and *das Mädchen*.

It's possible the same thinking applies if the baby is known to the persons involved in the conversation to be of one sex or the other, even if the name isn't used. For example, if two friends meet up and the one asks the other "*Wie geht's dem Baby?*", it might be acceptable to respond with a male or female pronoun because the sex of the baby to which the noun refers is known and, in a sense, overrides the purely linguistic consideration. But that's just speculation, I can't say for sure, because my German friends have only recently started having babies and I've not yet had occasion to ask or be corrected.

**UPDATE (4.10.2020)**

For a very dramatic example relevant to this topic, I've just been watching an episode of *Tatort* ([here](https://www.ardmediathek.de/daserste/video/tatort/todesbruecke/das-erste/Y3JpZDovL2Rhc2Vyc3RlLmRlL3RhdG9ydC9kNTBkZTQ2Zi1hOWNjLTQxMTEtOWJhOS04ZjEzNjBjZDA5YmM/)). At 1:24:57 the detective says to the man who's threatening to jump off the roof with his daughter: "Aber das da ist Ihr Kind. **Das** hat Sie lieb!" So even though the sex of the child is obvious to all present, the gender of the noun seems to override the natural sex. But this is only one example.

Comment: What you describe here is called *constructio ad sensum*.

Comment: I must say "Das Baby heißt Peter. Er ist 6 Monate alt." sounds incredibly weird to me. "Das Baby ist Peter. Er ist 6 Monate alt." is a lot better, maybe because the two nominatives in the first sentence kind of imply a change of subject to me.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: it doesn't sound weird to me at all. Well, "Peter" is not a credible baby's name in 2020, but otherwise I would say that.

Comment: Ja, das sind genau die Informationen, über die ich mich frage. Danke.

Comment: Die Nebenbedingung des Geschlechtswechsels ist, dass kein anderer Kandidat im Satz zuvor mit dem passenden Geschlecht erscheint, der semantisch im 2. Satz passt. "Das Kind heißt Peter und hat Hunger. Er ist grausam." Das wird als grausamer Hunger verstanden.

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort *»Baby«* ist sächlich, ebenso das Wort *»Kind«.* Sogar das Wort *»Mädchen«* ist sächlich:

- das Baby
- das Kind
- das Mädchen

Dieses grammatikalische Geschlecht ist eine Eigenschaft des Wortes. Man muss sich dieses grammatikalische Geschlecht als völlig unabhängig vom biologischen Geschlecht einer Person vorstellen.

Das Pronomen richtet sich nur nach dem grammatikalischen Geschlecht. Das Geschlecht des Pronomens stimmt immer mit dem Geschlecht jenes Substantivs überein, auf das es sich bezieht. Daher:

> - Das Baby liegt in der Wiege.
>   **Es** schläft. *(korrekt)*
>   <del>*Er*</del> schläft. *(falsch)*
>   <del>*Sie*</del> schläft. *(falsch)*
> - Das Kind ist im Garten.
>   **Es** spielt. *(korrekt)*
>   <del>*Er*</del> spielt. *(falsch)*
>   <del>*Sie*</del> spielt. *(falsch)*

Komplizierter ist es beim Mädchen. Dieses Wort ist zwar sächlich, im Gegensatz zu *Baby* oder *Kind,* wo man das biologische Geschlecht der Person nicht aus diesem Wort allein ableiten kann, ist bei einem Mädchen aber klar, dass es eine biologisch weibliche Person ist. Aus diesem Grund hat sich in ungefähr den letzten 50 Jahren für grammatisch sächliche Substantive, die biologisch weibliche Personen bezeichnen, eine Ausnahme etabliert. In diesen Fällen darf man auch ein weibliches Pronomen verwenden. Das war vor rund 50 Jahren (als ich zur Schule ging und das gelernt habe) noch nicht erlaubt.

Also:

> - Das Mädchen sitzt am Tisch.
>   **Es** isst. *(korrekt = Standard)*
>   <del>*Er*</del> isst. *(falsch)*
>   **Sie** isst. *(korrekt = Ausnahme)*
> - Das Fräulein öffnet die Tür.
>   **Es** geht. *(korrekt = Standard)*
>   <del>*Er*</del> geht. *(falsch)*
>   **Sie** geht. *(korrekt = Ausnahme)*
> - Das Weib steigt ins Auto.
>   **Es** fährt. *(korrekt = Standard)*
>   <del>*Er*</del> fährt. *(falsch)*
>   **Sie** fährt. *(korrekt = Ausnahme)*

Mehr darüber kannst in [einer anderen Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/59207/1487) von mir nachlesen, dort bringe ich auch noch ein interessantes Beispiel aus der Literatur. Es gibt nämlich ein Kinderbuch mit dem Titel *»Heidi kann brauchen, was **es** gelernt hat«.*

Comment: Gibt es diese Ausnahmen auch mit, z.B. "Das ??? sitzt am Tisch." -- "Er isst."

Comment: _**Sie/Er** ist das süsseste Baby (Kind), dass man sich vorstellen kann._ Ist das auch falsch?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ja. Das *dass* hat ein *s* zu viel. ;-)

Comment: @jmizv: Ja, aber selten: »Das Genie sitzt am Tisch. Er isst.« Sächliche Wörter, die das Wort *»Genie«* ersetzten könnten und sich auf eine männliche Person beziehen können, können aber immer auch auf Frauen bezogen sein. Sowohl das Genie, als auch das Talent oder auch das Arschloch könnten ebensogut auch Frauen sein. Mir fallen keine sächlichen Substantive ein, die ausschließlich männliche Personen bezeichnen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Nein, das ist nicht falsch, denn das Pronomen in diesem Satz bezieht sich ja nicht auf das Wort *»Baby«,* sondern auf ein ganz konkretes Baby, das ja ein ganz konkretes biologisches Geschlecht hat. Solche Pronomen stimmen im Geschlecht zwar immer (bis auf die genannten Ausnahmen) mit dem Geschlecht des referenzierten Substantivs überein, aber Pronomen können sich auch auf ungenannte Ideen im Kontext beziehen. ...

Comment: ... Beispiel: 2 Freunde warten auf den Bus. Eine stark betrunkene Person erregt deren Aufmerksamkeit. Daraufhin sagt ein Freund zum anderen: »Na, **der** ist aber ganz schön besoffen.« Das Demonstrativpronomen *»der«* ist hier männlich, weil es sich auf eine männliche Person bezieht, die aber weder vorher noch im Satz mit einem Wort bezeichnet worden ist. Und das Pronomen, mit dem dein Satz beginnt, bezieht sich ebenso auf eine Idee im Kontext, und nicht auf das Wort *»Baby«.*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich wage zu widersprechen. Die Einführung der Person als Person legt nahe, dass es gerade keine männliche ist, und sich der eine Freund einfach im Irrtum befindet, dessen wörtliche Rede sprachlich unabhängig von der Erzählerstimme ist, die aus einer überlegenen Position heraus aber besser weiß, zumindest offen lässt.